# How is satellite uplink secured from DOS attack?

Tags: denial-of-service, satellite

How satellite communication is secured from Denial of Service attack on up-link frequency as anyone can create interference?

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer. My educated guess is that nobody bothers with purely destructive attacks such as jamming because you usually hardly gain anything, and you need special equipment to overpower something as distant as a satellite (probably a few hundred bucks unless you *really* know what you're doing and can build a custom one from cheap components). Extreme directionality is also difficult to achieve so you'd probably have quite a lot of leakage, making it possible for authorities to find you.